# Webstorm, не работает emmet в jade файлах

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

Столкнулся с проблемой автодополнения emmet в jade файлах после Sublime Text 3. Например пишем "!", а получаем:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    html
      head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        title Document
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="")
      body
```

Есть ли способ добиться такого в Webstorm?
(плагин jade у меня стоит)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К сожалению, Emmet для Jade шаблонов сейчас не поддерживается. Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за [WEB-18099](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18099)

Comment: О, давно хотел спросить, Вы же официальная поддержка, так? Вы регулярно все вопросы на ru.so по тегам webstorm смотрите или только эпизодически? То есть если у меня коллега что по вебшторму спросит, вживую или на другом форуме, имеет его смысл отправлять на ru.so спрашивать?

Comment: Просто есть категория программистов для которых обратиться в офф техподдержку это "ужас-ужас-коммуникация", а задать вопрос на so - дело нормальное

Comment: да, официальная. Стараюсь просматривать вопросы по соотв тегам, но не всегда получается - у вопросов на so самый низкий приоритет:( Ведь на мне еще официальный саппорт + форумы + youtrack... Так что советую все-таки обращаться в техподдержку. Ну хотя бы на форум писать (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367229-WebStorm). Иначе ответа можно и не дождаться:(